# Paypal iphone timeout error again and again

Tags: iphone, paypal

I am creating an simple app, and integrating paypal library downloaded from

[Paypal Library Link](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-payment-libraries)

after adding to my project, I just write few lines of code in my ViewController.m

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX]; 


//We have successfully initialized and are ready to pay
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getInstance] getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:@selector(payWithPayPal) andButtonType:BUTTON_278x43 andButtonText:BUTTON_TEXT_PAY];
[self.view addSubview:button];


[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void) payWithPayPal {

NSLog(@"VEER SUTHAR");

PayPal *payObject=[PayPal getInstance];
PayPalPayment *obj=[[PayPalPayment alloc]init];
obj.recipient=@"veer.developer@gmail.com";
obj.paymentCurrency=@"USD";
obj.description=@"Teddy Bear";
obj.merchantName=@"Veer";
obj.subTotal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"]; 
[payObject checkoutWithPayment:obj];        

}
```

I am facing two major issue,

1. Most of time it doesn't enable the button of paypal, and gives error
2. If it does enable button, as I click it, and enter the email id and password, it gives error always like below

"Your Session has time out. Your payment has not been processed. Please  try sending again"

I am unable to understand the issue over here, Even I have valid email account for sandbox

Can any one explain me the real issue and it solution,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using 3G network.
For some reason it was more reliable to me when working with PayPal.

Also check if you are running in a background thread or on the main thread. PayPal have both options but the code for each is a bit different and it affects this issue.

For the session timeout error, make sure you use the SADNBOX app key and environment.
And make sure you are using the sandbox test user and not your real paypal user